# Javascript how to continue timer with a some already provided time in seconds

Tags: javascript

Have a requirement to Display a timer in the screen. But in case the application crashes the other requirement is to restart the timer from the time it stopped.

I am new to java script was able to add the timer to the screen with the below code , also able to capture the time i have when the application crashed so am able to get the Time when stopped from the backend but any any idea how can i utilize the existing timer value to start from that point.

current code which works in normal processing of application:-

```
function Timer(id) {
  var startTimeMs = new Date().getTime();
  var currDateMs = new Date().getTime();
  var timeElapsed = currDateMs - startTimeMs;
  var hour = Math.floor(
    (timeElapsed % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
  );
  if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
  var minute = Math.floor((timeElapsed % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute;
  var second = Math.floor((timeElapsed % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  if (second < 10) second = "0" + second;
  $("#" + id).html("" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);

}
```

---

Now i have the total seconds value as well as the value in timer 
so lets say the application was up for 86415 seconds and time on the screen was Time: "24:00:15" when application crashed , now need help how do i modify the above code to start counting after above time?

Thanks.## Heading ##

Comment: Do you realize how unreadable your code is ? Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) correctly.

Comment: I have formatted your code and suggested an edit to make the code readable

Comment: Thanks for updating .. yeah i messed up while posting  it..

Answer (score 1):

Set a local storage variable every time the timer changes. Then when your page loads, just check if that storage item exists. I'm not sure the entire application of your timer but there's a difference between sessionStorage and localStorage. sessionStorage will only store a variable as long as the browser window stays open. localStorage stores it indedfinitely or until the user clears the cache, even through browser close/reopens. So depending on your need, you can choose which storage to use. This should get you started.

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('time'){
     $("#" + id).html(localStorage.getItem('time');
    //rest of code to continue timer counting down
   } else {

 timer = setInterval(function() {
        var currDateMs1 = new Date().getTime();
        var timeElapsed1 = currDateMs1 - startTimeMs;
        var hour1 = Math.floor(
          (timeElapsed1 % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );
        if (hour1 < 10) hour1 = "0" + hour1;
        var minute1 = Math.floor((timeElapsed1 % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        if (minute1 < 10) minute1 = "0" + minute1;
        var second1 = Math.floor((timeElapsed1 % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        if (second1 < 10) second1 = "0" + second1;
        $("#" + id).html("" + hour1 + ":" + minute1 + ":" + second1);
        localStorage.setItem('time', "" + hour1 + ":" + minute1 + ":" + second1);
      }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: does this line still hold true in the above code? var timeElapsed1 = currDateMs1 - startTimeMs;

Comment: My problem is how to continue counting after that value which i already have.. i am able to display the value in the screen as i am doing a backend call to retrive that.. but not able to continue the counting from that point...  it again resets to a new value instead of extending from that point and adding seconds to it

Comment: i didn't include that in my example but you can make it work. Essentially all you need to do is wrap the entire functionality within an if statement that checks for the value of a storage item (session or local). Then the last thing you do is update that storage item with the current value of the timer after all your calculations are done.

Comment: what kind of call are you  making to the back end? is it php that's pulling from a database or something?

Comment: May be i am not able to explain properly - below is my issue -  so once the applicaton crash and i restart the application,  i have the total seconds value as well as the value in timer so lets say the application was up for 86415 seconds and time on the screen was Time: "24:00:15" when application crashed , now using the value  Time: "24:00:15"  or  86415 seconds  as base how can i increment the timer

Comment: where are you storing that value? in the browser? or are you using node or php and saving to a server?

Comment: I am saving the value in the backend DB .. saving and retrieving the value is not a problem i am able to retrieve the value as well as save it ... the problem is how do i increment from that value as timer?

Comment: can you actually give me the technology you're using so i can give you some functional code? are you using a framework like laravel or something? are you using an MVC style of building? Without knowing this, the only thing I can say is "pass that variable to your html, use an if-statement to check if it's null. if it's not null, start at the value of the variable." I'm sure you were already able to get that far on your own though